# How to build this php array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$items  = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
$items = explode(" ", $items);
```

$items is my array, how can I have it turn into this

Like how can I make word1 be a key and a value?

```
"word1" => "word1"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$newArray =` [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine)`($items, $items);`

Comment: That seems like the best way, it didn't work how I hoped though \, my previous code posted above, "word1" actually is canada territories and some of them have a space in them, British Columbia Manitoba New Brunswick, that is 3 locations but my function made it into 5 values in the array, how can I get around this?

Comment: I think you'll struggle to parse that string into an array, because it requires knowledge of the places. Could you get the source string with a different separator?

Comment: You really need a better separator, something that is never used in the values you want to retrieve. Perhaps a semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($items as $item) {
$newArr[$item] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$items  = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
$temp = explode(" ", $items);
$result = array();
foreach ($temp as $value) {
  $result[$value] = $value; 
}
```